# How to keep only lines whose next line is identical

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I try to parse a file using **sed** command and keep only lines that have a duplicate at the next respective line.

## Exemple

(written in a file named `test`)

```
line
line
line
line1
line
line3
line1
line2
line2
line
```

## Expected output

```
line
line
line2
```

## My shell command

```
cat test | sed -rn '$!N; /^(.*)\n\1/P; D'
```

## Output

```
line
line
line
line
line2
```

I wonder what is wrong in this command ? Why did I get 2 additional `line`s ??

Comment: That looks like exactly what `unid -d` does. `have a duplicate at the next respective line.` - the second `line` shouldn't be in the output, the next line after `line` is `line2`.

Comment: @KamilCuk `uniq -d` wouldn't work here, as I think OP wants `n-1` lines to be retained for `n` consecutive duplicates

Comment: As per OP, "keep only lines that have a duplicate at the next respective line", why there's second `line` in the expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest using `sed` for this task.

However, you only had a minor issue with the command you tried. You need to compare the next line completely, so add `$` anchor after `\1`

```
$ sed -nE '$!N; /^(.*)\n\1$/P; D' ip.txt
line
line
line2
```

Without the anchor, `line` would match strings like `line1`, `linexyaz` etc. If you change the input such that there are no partial matches, then your command would have worked

```
$ cat ip.txt
line
line
line
cline1
line
zline3
line1
line2
line2
line
$ sed -nE '$!N; /^(.*)\n\1/P; D' ip.txt
line
line
line2
```

Comment: Perhaps `sed -n 'N;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/P;D' file` is suffice?

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient. The -E option is for extended regex (sed has basic regex enabled by default)

Answer (score 5):

If you are ok with `awk` could you please try following once.

```
awk 'prev==$0 && prev{print} {prev=$0}' Input_file
```

***OR***

```
awk 'prev==$0 && prev; {prev=$0}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code now.

```
awk '                 ##Starting awk program here.
prev==$0 && prev{     ##Checking condition if prev variable is equal to current line and prev is NOT NULL.
  print               ##Printing the current line then, as per OP request.
}                     ##Closing BLOCK for prev==$0 && prev condition here.
{
  prev=$0             ##Setting variable prev to current line.
}
' Input_file          ##Mentioning Input_file name here(which is getting passed to awk).
```

Comment: checking empty lines seems unnecessary to me. `p==$0; {p=$0}` should do.

Answer (score 0):

With `(GNU sed) 4.2.2`, that supports `-z`:

```
sed -rz ':a;s/(^|\n)([^\a\n]*)\n\2\n/\1\2\a\n\2\n/g;ta;' test | sed -rn 's/\a$//p'
```